# "The space of all lines on a plane is an open Möbius Band."

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology

I have come across this sentence when I was reading something about algebraic topology:

> The space of all lines on a plane is an open Möbius Band.

I don't quite understand this, can anyone explain this to me? Thank You.

Comment: Please do your research first: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_strip which contains a subsection precisely on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=M%C3%B6bius_strip&oldid=504333359#Open_M.C3.B6bius_band):

> The open Möbius band is formed by deleting the [boundary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_%28topology%29) of the standard Möbius band. It is constructed from the set $S = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 0 ≤ x ≤ 1 \text{ and } 0 < y < 1 \}$ by identifying (glueing) the points $(0,y)$ and $(1,1−y)$ for all $0 < y < 1$.
>
> **Occurrence and use in mathematics**
>
> The space of unoriented lines in the plane is [diffeomorphic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffeomorphic) to the open Möbius band.[[6]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_strip#cite_note-5)
>
> To see why, notice that each line in the plane has an equation $ax + by + c = 0$ for fixed constants $a$, $b$ and $c$. We can identify the equation $ax + by + c = 0$ with the point $(a,b,c)$. However, the line given by $ax + by + c = 0$ is also given by $λ(ax + by + c) = (λa)x + (λb)y + (λc) = 0$ for all $λ ≠ 0$.
>
> These equations, which give the same line, are identified with the points $(λa,λb,λc)$. Thus, the space of lines in the plane is a [(proper) subset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_subset#proper_subset) of the [real projective plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_plane); where the equation $ax + by + c = 0$ corresponds to the point $(a:b:c)$ in [homogeneous coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates). It is only a subset because some equations of the form $ax + by + c = 0$ do not give lines. We need to disallow $a = b = 0$ to be sure that the equation $ax + by + c = 0$ does indeed give a line. The space of unoriented lines in the plane is given by deleting the point $(0:0:c) = (0:0:1)$ from the real projective plane. This space is exactly the open Möbius band.

Comment: Come on, at least write up the formulae in LaTeX even if you're going to copy-paste the rest...

Comment: I almost got it, but I don't understand that why "The space of unoriented lines in the plane is given by deleting the point (0:0:c)=(0:0:1) from the real projective plane. This space is exactly the open Möbius band." - could you help? Thanks

Comment: I would really appreciate any intuition someone could offer about the particular question raised by 1LiterTears...why is the real projective plane with a single point removed topologically equivalent to the mobius band?