# The set of lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a Möbius band?

Tags: general-topology

I encountered a hard-to-believe and hard-to-understand statement in this problem:

Let $\mathcal{L} = \{\textrm{lines in}\ \mathbb{R}^2\}$. Consider the 2-to-1 map $f: S^1 \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathcal{L}$ given by $(\theta,x) \mapsto L_{\theta,x} = \{t(\mathrm{cos}\,\theta,\mathrm{sin}\,\theta)+x(-\mathrm{sin}\,\theta,\mathrm{cos}\,\theta): t\in\mathbb{R}\}$.

Show that for almost every $(\theta,x) \in S^1\times\mathbb{R}$, we have that $f^{-1}(L_{\theta,x})$ is a smooth submanifold of $X$.

*Remark*: The set of lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a Möbius band.

So my question is, why the set is a Möbius band? And I really hope to get some help to understand the function $f$ - how it work: why $t(\mathrm{cos}\,\theta,\mathrm{sin}\,\theta)+x(-\mathrm{sin}\,\theta,\mathrm{cos}\,\theta)$
gives lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$? And why it is 2-to-1? Thank you very much for your guidance.

Comment: this answer should clear things up for you http://math.stackexchange.com/a/176780/52216

Comment: Thank you very much @exitingcorpse. I almost got it, but I don't understand that why "The space of unoriented lines in the plane is given by deleting the point (0:0:c)=(0:0:1) from the real projective plane. This space is exactly the open Möbius band."

Comment: have a look at the pictures on this page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_plane

Comment: remove a point from the centre (all the points are effectively the same). now stretch it out into a little circle, and make a horizontal cut across the whole thing. draw some little arrows on it so you don't forget where you cut. now can you see how to reglue the pieces to get the middle picture?

Comment: (i can draw some pictures for you if you'd like)

Comment: hmm, pictures... :-D

Comment: I kind of pictured what you said - a Mobius band with infinitely long width, right?

Comment: Assuming what I said above is correct, then I could image $\mathbb{R}^2$ being a Mobius band. But why it can be represented by $L_{\theta,x} = \{t(\mathrm{cos}\,\theta,\mathrm{sin}\,\theta)+x(-\mathrm{sin}\,\theta,\mathrm{cos}\,\theta): t\in\mathbb{R}\}$? Thanks!

Comment: here's an album: http://imgur.com/a/VNgVF you should be able to do this in a slightly quicker way

Comment: I got it, thanks - the pictures are really very helpful. But I still have two questions: why this construction represents a Möbius band? Conversely, why $L_{\theta,x} = \{t(\mathrm{cos}\,\theta,\mathrm{sin}\,\theta)+x(-\mathrm{sin}\,\theta,\mathrm{cos}\,\theta): t\in\mathbb{R}\}$ represents lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$? Oh, and why it is 2-to-1. Thank you. =>

Comment: we've seen that the space of unoriented lines gives the open möbiusband. when $t=0$, you get the point $(-x\sin(\theta),x\cos(\theta)$. the line emanates from this point at the angle $\theta$. varying $x$ gives you exactly one line in the equivalence class of parallel lines to this. and the map is certainly $2$-$1$, as $\theta \mapsto \pi + \theta$ and $x \mapsto -x$ gives you the same line

Comment: @exitingcorpse It seems that the chain of your comments answered the questions. Please consider summarizing them in the answer box.

Comment: @jellyfish: the first sentence of the quote  in your first comment is explained  by the bijection asociating to $ [a:b:c]\in \mathbb P^2 \;([a:b:c] \neq [0:0:1])$ the affine line $ax+by +c=0$.

Comment: @citedcorpse what exactly is occurring in step 8 of your photos? the orientation of the arrows seems to change

Answer (score 6):

First, the remark (I think it is more important and also simpler to see). "The set of lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$ should immediately make us think of the projective plane. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176763/the-space-of-all-lines-on-a-plane-is-an-open-mobius-band/176780#176780) previous answer shows why the space of unoriented lines is just a punctured projective plane.

Depending on your exposure to the classification of surfaces, you may declare the problem finished at this stage. After all, one construction of the projective plane is to glue a disc along the boundary of a möbiusband. Or you can try to convert a diagram for the punctured projective plane into a diagram for an (open) möbiusband. I have uploaded a series of diagrams depicting this [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWKB0.jpg). You should be able to see that there is a slightly more efficient way of manipulating the diagram than what I did.

Now we just need to see why that particular map gives a parametrisation of the unoriented lines. I think a more sophisticated mind than mine should be able to explicitly see how this is a copy of $\mathbb{R}$ twisting along the circle, but I don't know the formalism to explain that.

We wish to understand how $x$ and $\theta$ determine the line $L_{\theta, x}$ geometrically. The simplest point is when $t = 0$, and this gives us $(-x \sin\theta, x \cos\theta)$. Then the part of the line with $t$ in front clearly says that the line emanates from this point at an angle of $\theta$. So modifying $x$ with $\theta$ fixed gives us all the lines in the equivalence class of parallel lines to the $t=0$ one. You can then show that we get *all* lines, and we get the same line when we do the involution $\theta \mapsto \pi + \theta, x \mapsto -x$.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a geometric proof that the open subset $L:=\mathbb P^2\setminus \{[1:0:0]\}\subset \mathbb P^2$ of the projective plane  is isomorphic to the total space of the bundle $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(1) $, where  $\mathbb P^1$ is identified with the line $P\subset \mathbb P^2$  given by  $z_0=0$ and the  projection morphism of the bundle is  $L\to \mathbb P^1:[z_0:z_1:z_2]\mapsto [0:z_1:z_2]$ .

Let  $U_i\subset L \;(i=1,2)$ be the open subset $z_i\neq 0$.
The trivializations of $L$ are then given by :
$$f_1:U_1\to \mathbb (P^1\cap U_1)\times \mathbb R: [z_0:z_1:z_2]\mapsto ([0:z_1:z_2], z_0/z_1)$$$$f_2:U_2\to (\mathbb P^1\cap U_2)\times \mathbb R: [z_0:z_1:z_2]\mapsto ([0:z_1:z_2], z_0/z_2) $$

The transition cocycle is determined by $g_{12}([z_0:z_1:z_2])=z_2/z_1$, which shows that our bundle is indeed $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(1)$.

The above proof is valid on a completely arbitrary field and has an obvious generalization to $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}(1)$, whose total space is thus shown to be isomorphic to $\mathbb P^{n+1}\setminus \{[1:0:\cdots:0]\}$.
Over $\mathbb R$ the total space of $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(1) $ is the Möbius strip: this may be given as the definition of the Möbius strip or necessitates a proof if the Möbius strip is defined in another way.

Comment: The OP finds it hard to understand why $f$ maps to lines, let alone why it proves that lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$ are homeomorphic to the Möbius strip, and you talk about bundles, cocycles, arbitrary fields, projective space and total space in your answer? You must be trolling

Answer (score 1):

I feel like the existing answers, while mathematically correct, may be a bit much for someone new to topology. Let me try a less formal explanation why "The Möbius strip is equivalent (homeomorphic) to the set of non-oriented lines in the plane".

Consider the standard construction of a Möbius strip by gluing the vertical ends of a flat strip of paper of width $[0,2\pi)$ and height $(-1,1)$ "with a 180° twist".
Clearly you can specify any point on the strip *uniquely* by the "angle" $\theta\in [0,2\pi)$ and the "height" $x\in (-1,1)$; this is simply the parametrization of the paper strip before you glue it.

Similarly you can specify any line in the plane *uniquely* by an angle $\theta \in [0,\pi)$ (where does the line point?) and a height $(-\infty,\infty)$ (how far do we translate the line from the origin towards where it points?). This is what your $f$ does, except it does it "twice" by allowing $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$.

Note that $[0,\pi)$ and $(-\infty, \infty)$ are homeomorphic (can be stretched or shrunk in)to $[0,2\pi)$ and $(-1,1)$. Since they have the same parametrizations (up to homeomorphism) it seems the Möbius strip and the set of lines in the plane are really the same. However, to really be able to conclude that, we still need to talk about the "edges" of our parametrizations. To define the Möbius strip by gluing the edges of a strip means that we map the limiting angle $\theta\to2\pi$ to the same points as $\theta=0$ but with the heights $x\in(-1,1)$ inverted.

Is that property true for our parametrization of the lines too? Yes! The horizontal lines that you get for $\theta=0$ are exactly those that you get if you let $\theta\to\pi$, but the former diverge upwards as you increase the "height" parameter, while the latter diverge downwards.