# Set of affine lines in $\mathbb R^2$ maps to open Mobius strip

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

This is an example in lecture for a chart:

\begin{split}
M &= \{\text{affine line in } \mathbb R^2\}\\
U &= \{\ell \in M \ |\  \ell  \text{ not vertical}\}\\
V &= \{\ell \in M \ |\ \ell \text{ not horizontal} \}
\end{split}

\begin{split}
\phi &: U \rightarrow \mathbb R^2, \ell \mapsto (m,b) \text{ with }\ell \text{ given by } \ell: y= mx+b \\     
\psi &: V \rightarrow \mathbb R^2, \ell \mapsto (n,c) \text{ with }\ell \text{ given by } \ell: x= ny+c
\end{split}

So: $(\psi \circ \phi^{-1})(m,b) = ({1\over m} , {-b \over m})$

Could someone explain why here we obtain a 2-dimensional surface defined as an open mobius strip.

based on :[The set of lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a Möbius band?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/418048/the-set-of-lines-in-mathbbr2-is-a-m%C3%B6bius-band)
i understand that a set of affine lines in $R^2$ makes the projective space, which can be formed by gluing a mobius strip and a circle, or two mobius strips, however maybe could i get further explanation following this specific example?

Comment: It looks me strange that $(\psi \circ \phi^{-1})(m,b) = ({1\over m} , {-b \over m})$ doesn't involve parameters $n,c$ as well.

Comment: There is a typo, the domain of $\psi$ is $V$. What is $U\cap V$? Can you  see how the change of variables acts on different components?

Comment: $U \cap V$ is the set of affine lines which are neither vertical or horizontal. and the map takes the slope and constant to the $R^2$ plane. but i dont quite see the change of variable, do you mind elaborating?

Comment: I'm trying to guide you to the answer without telling it to you. Think about gluing strips together to get a Mobius band and try to recognize it in the example.